# How can I use App.config to store urls and retrieve the urls in testing Selenium tests with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, app-config

I created an App.config file to store urls instead of having them hardcoded throughout my unit tests so if the url changes I only have one place I need to change them in.  This is my App.config(urls were changed for posting purposes):

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Home" value="https://home.com"/>
    <add key="AnotherPage" value="https://anotherpage.com"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In my tests, I am trying to use the urls like this:

```
using Xunit;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Homepage.Tests.UI.Tests
{
    public class HomePageShould
    {
        [Fact]
        public static void Open()
        {
            var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Home"];
            using IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

Result Message: System.ArgumentNullException : Argument 'url' cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')

I also tried this: var _homeUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Home");

And get the same error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This wont work because *App.config* file is automatically generated when new project is created. Most likely, you have created wrong type of project.

You can find more regarding Configurations and Selenium [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/manage-read-configurations-using-configurationmanager-csharp/).

P.S. I would post this as comment, but my reputation is <50. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't see how what I am doing is anything different than in the article.

Answer (score 0):

App.config file supposed to be automatically created while creating a project. So, perhaps you don't need to create it manually if you do so. May be manual creation of this file could be the problem that not to find the value under the key. Other than that your code looks okay to get the value.

Comment: Do asp.net core applications create the app.config automatically?  I created my test in visual studio by selecting xunit test project template .net core.

Comment: No. Dot net core does not necessarily require app.config file though.